Вылет приложения при входе в цветные режимы
Когда я перехожу в режим Viewport или Shading у меня вылетает Blender, текущий проект не сохраняется, а проекты, сохраненные в этих режимах у меня вылетают не запустившись. Мое устройство: Huawei Mate Book D 15 BoM-VFP9 (53013TUE) Ryzen 7 5700U 8 ГБ SSD 512 ГБ AMD Radeon 15.6 IPS FHD (1920x1080)

Ноутбук какого цвета?

Цвет Silver, хотя не знаю, как это поможет

А что из всего того, что вы указали в вопросе, может помочь идентифицировать проблему? Когда что-то "вылетает", то смотрят в логах, в Windows event viewer и указывают в вопросе. А то ваш вопрос как "не заводится Форд 2012-го года, хетчбек, ABS, кондиционер, салон кожа, покрышки зимние Bridgestone - в чем причина?"

А как в Windows event viewer найти лог определенного приложения, если не сложно, подскажите?

Нет под рукой Windows. Если на память, то Windows Logs -> Application. И там ищите blender. https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-view-and-analyze-logs-with-windows-event-viewer/ - полно информации, если в поиск вбить.
